# Get uploaded file absolute location using apache common file upload

Tags: java, javascript, apache

I need absolute path for the uploaded file. I tried with out enctype,it only returns the file name by request.getParameter.Tried javascript also return a freaky path. I know this is for security reason. Is there any way i can get the file location? .

```
Html code is 
<form action="test.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" ><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: To tell u d truth there is no way to get the location of the file.

Comment: Absolute location on client machine? Why do you need this? This sounds a little bit strange. Could you explain your root problem?

Comment: i am uploading a csv file,i only need the file name to update the table contain.it works with default eclipse browser but not in chrome or firefox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading a file in Java Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237031/uploading-a-file-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score -1):

done some patch up work.hard code the specific folder location and append the file name.so my limitaion is the file should come from that particular folder