# Reading excel file inside a servlet (multipart data)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am supposed to read an excel file on the server and store it in the database as a table. 
I was using ApachePOI to read the excel file by picking up the excel file from the hard disk.
Imagine a client uploads a file and sends it to a server, the server wouldn't have access to the hard disk of the client. So now I want to send it as a multipart form-data and then read it on the server.

I have been reading on the internet as well as Stackoverflow  but have not found an answer(although there are examples to read a text file).

Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237031/uploading-a-file-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Accept the uploaded multiPart File in your servlet.
2. The servlet should then write the uploaded file to the server's disk.
3. The servlet can then read the uploaded file from the server's disk.